# Using Class from jar file in JavaScript file

Tags: javascript

I have jar file that contains a MatLab function, and I need to use this function in JavaScript file. I would like to know how can I use jar file in js file. How can I import it in js file and use it. 
Thank you

Comment: Java is not JavaScript and there is no specific way to just port code over. Look for or write an equivalent function in JS.

Comment: Can you tell me please how to convert classification function to JavaScript

Comment: Step 1: Understand what the function does. Step 2: Write a function with the same functionality in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the stackoverflow.

There's no such a proper way to run the function at an optimal speed.

Probably you may be interested in this emulator: http://plasma-umass.github.io/doppio-demo/
 [image: the emulator can process java class file]

But more over than the java thing, the Matlab function call will not able to run because I believe the java program execute the Matlab instance in background to process the Matlab function and get you the result = means the system should have matlab installed. Mathworks requires you to hold a [proper license](https://www.mathworks.com/pricing-licensing.html) to run the code on any machine, or [special way to compile it](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/93769-how-can-i-distribute-an-application-that-is-developed-using-matlab) + [runtime](https://www.mathworks.com/products/compiler/mcr.html) installed.
Executing any program outside of the browser is highly discouraged or nearly not possible ([sandboxed](https://www.veracode.com/security/javascript-security)). Most of the recent browsers just don't have any bridge to the operating system because of its vulnerability.

So there are 3 options:

1. Consider to use Matlab server version.
2. Consider to try http://octave-online.net/ to find out your matlab function actually works independently, and get the function work.
3. Port the function in javascript.